# Spring Webflow - access exception using transition.on-exception attribute

Tags: exception, spring-webflow

I wondering how can I access exception object using on-exception attribute?
My current configuration looks like this:

```
<transition on-exception="{business_exception}" to="errorView" >
</transition>
```

I have to access some exception attribute in errorView.
Does anybody know how can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

This is a rather [undocumented](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-922) part of Spring Web Flow, but according to [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?29312-transition-on-exception) thread on SpringSource forum, you can access the exception directly on your view as attributes `stateException` and `rootCauseException`.

Comment: This could work. I found anather solution here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58614-Can-evaluate-method-in-on-exception-transition-see-exception   "you only have direct EL access to the outer-level (via flowExecutionException) and the root-cause (via rootCauseException) exceptions"

Answer (score 3):

rootCauseException and flowExecutionException are the right scoped variables that are accessible in the flow. These variables are populated after the transition to the new flow,so in a pseudo sense:

```
<transition on-exception="{business_exception}" to="errorView" >
</transition>

<view-state id="errorView">
  <on-entry>
    <evaluate expression="exceptionHandler(flowExecutionException)"/>
    <evaluate expression="exceptionHandler(rootCauseException)"/> 
  </on-entry>
</view-state>
```